# Ubuntu isn't recognising some of my 4G modems.. they are plugged into a USB hub

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, huawei

I have 17 Huawei E3372h dongles attached to my Ubuntu machine, across 3 Orico 10 port USB hubs.

```
lsusb
```

Will show only 11 of the Modems , and recognises the ports at 7 port USB hubs.

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 049: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 032: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 031: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 030: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 008 Device 055: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 009: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 007: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 008 Device 024: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 022: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 018: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 033: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 013: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 008 Device 047: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 008: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 008 Device 006: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

None of them are in mass storage mode... does anyone know what could be causing the issue here?

Update #1

lsusb -tv

```
/:  Bus 09.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
            |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
                ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
                |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                    ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
                    |__ Port 2: Dev 36, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                        ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                    |__ Port 2: Dev 36, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                        ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                    |__ Port 4: Dev 30, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
                        ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
                        |__ Port 1: Dev 109, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                            ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                        |__ Port 1: Dev 109, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                            ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                        |__ Port 2: Dev 34, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                            ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                        |__ Port 2: Dev 34, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                            ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
            |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
                ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
                |__ Port 1: Dev 21, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                    ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131 (Mass storage mode)
                |__ Port 6: Dev 11, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 6: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 4: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 4: Dev 15, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 2: Dev 19, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 2: Dev 19, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 7: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 7: Dev 13, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 5: Dev 8, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 5: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 3: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
                |__ Port 3: Dev 18, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                    ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
            |__ Port 2: Dev 26, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
            |__ Port 2: Dev 26, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
            |__ Port 3: Dev 27, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
            |__ Port 3: Dev 27, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
            |__ Port 1: Dev 25, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
            |__ Port 1: Dev 25, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
                ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
    ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
    ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
    ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
    ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Update #2

MY rules:

/etc/udev/rules.d/41-huawei_e3372.rules that contains:

```
# Huawei E3372
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="xxxx", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

And yes they are now connected directly to the machine.. some modems are in mass storage mode or are switching back to it - cant figure out why

Comment: Could you provide output from more informative `lsusb -tv`?

Comment: Updated the question, thanks

Comment: So, did you stack USB hubs? I mean did you connect one 10 port hup to one of ports of another 10 port hub?

Comment: @Serg yes. lots of my modems keep switching back into 'mass storage mode' even though I have a rules file in etc/udev/rules.d

Comment: Can you: a) attach each 10 port hub _directly_ to pc usb connectors? b) provide your rules?

Comment: So did you manage to see all 17 modems regardless of their mode?

Comment: @Serg no actually. Even though the hubs are directly connected to machine, there are still 2 modems not showing under $lsusb. The modems themselves have a steady blue light, and look like they are connected!

Comment: Did `lsusb -tv` output change? Could you provide it if any changes?

Comment: I thought that we were working this elsewhere? Anyway, no, you can't stack hubs. And your rule still shows xxxx for idProduct... it should be 14db. And a reboot is required for usb_modeswitch to flip the dongles.

Comment: @heynnema This question became the other one once I realised it was a Mass Storage issues rather than something wrong with my USB Ports.. I actually pasted that rule from your answer so the xxx for idProduct was 1f01 .. shall i add 14db or swap it? The mass storage modems idProduct is 1f01

Comment: The product code doesn't change. Your lsusb shows 12d1:14db, so 14db should replace the xxxx in the rule. Then a reboot is required. We did this before.

Comment: I've done this, yet some modems are still booting into mass storage mode and trying to run HiLink software